# how can I replace consecutive "\n" with only one "\n" from a string in a variable

Tags: bash, sed

(I will use _ instead of BLANK and \n instead of line break to describe the situation better:)

if I execute

```
str_text=`vilistextum -u -p - - <<< "$str_html"`;
printf "$str_text"
```

the outpot is something like:

```
THISISAWord
\n_
\n___
\n_
ANOTHERWORD
\n_
...
\n__
ANOTHERWORD
\n
\n
\n__
\n_
```

how can I replace consecutive `\n` `\n`  and `\n \n` with only one `\n` from a string in a variable ? I want to compact consecutive NEWLINES to one.
I want to get is something like:

```
THISISAWord
\n
ANOTHERWORD
\n
ANOTHERWORD
```

I tried something like

```
str_text=`vilistextum -u -p - - <<< "$str_html"  | sed 's/\n//g'`;
```

but the sed is not working like I imagine it.

## ==== SOLUTION ====

If you ever want to transform something higher then HTML 3.2 to Text 
without to save in files (witch kills performance) then use the following

```
str_text=$(vilistextum - - <<< "$str_html");
str_text=$(awk 'NF{print $0}' ORS='\n' <<< "$str_text");
str_text=$(sed 's/\\n//g' <<< "$str_text" );
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: do you have actual `\n` in there or are those line breaks?

Comment: @eichertc Can you please update your question with what issue you are running into?

Comment: Don't edit the solution into the question - that's what the green checkmark (accept) is for, to indicate what solution worked for you.

Comment: Why do you say : It's difficult to tell what is being asked here.? My English is not so good, but I think you know what consecutive new lines are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `awk` you can try something like:

```
awk 'NF{print $0}' ORS='\n\n' <<< "$str_text"
```

#### Test:

```
$ cat -vet <<< "$str_text"
$
THISISAWORD$
   $
      $
 $
$
ANOTHERWORD$
$
  $
 $
ANOTHERWORD$
    $
 $
$
$
$ awk 'NF{print $0}' ORS='\n\n' <<< "$str_text"
THISISAWORD

ANOTHERWORD

ANOTHERWORD
```

So you can do:

```
$ str_text=$(awk 'NF{print $0}' ORS='\n\n' <<< "$str_text")
$ echo "$str_text"
THISISAWORD

ANOTHERWORD

ANOTHERWORD
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want

```
cmd | sed -n 's/.*[^[:space:]].*/&\n/p'
```

- `-n` switch turns off the default print-each-line behavior.
- `s/../../p` says print those lines where substitution occurs.
- `&` contains the string matching the entire pattern on the left side of `s///`

If a line contains at least a single non-whitespace character, add a newline to the end of that line. Otherwise (lines that contains only whitespace-characters like newline and space), 
ignore them.

---

`sed 's/\n//g'` doesn't work because `sed` uses newline as record separators. So instead of seeing the file as `line1\nline2\nline3` etc., it sees it as `line1`, `line2`, `line3` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Taking your question to be:

> How do I remove lines with only blank characters?

The answer would be

```
grep -E \\w
```

If you also want to get rid of trailing spaces in non-blank lines:

```
grep -E \\w | sed -r 's/ +$//g'
```

Comment: it returns something like :

`?? getopt returned character code 0165 u??
\n
THELASTLINE`

Comment: For what source? Upload it somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

To see only lines containing something:

grep . file

found [here](http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/11962-cat-empty-lines.html)

man pages:

> A period (.), when used outside of a bracket expression, is a basic Regular Expression that matches any printable or nonprintable character except

Answer (score 0):

```
    Kaizen ~/so_test $  cat ztempfile3.txt | nl | grep -v '\n' | tr '[0-9]' '\n'

    THISISAWord

    ANOTHERWORD

    ANOTHERWORD
```

was just trying stuff ..... does this help ?